# PHP Inheritance Accessing Variables

Tags: php, inheritance

So I have this code, see below. I am running an error while getting a protected value. Thought that protected values will be inherited. I was figuring out why we need to call `parent::__construct()`, while we just can extend a class.

If you could tell me whats wrong and how can I do it the right way, that would be awesome.

```
    <?php 
    /**
    * DogWords
    */

    class DogWords
    {
        protected $words = array('Wrr', 'Grr', 'Weeee', 'Houou');
    }

    /**
    * Dog Class
    */
    class Dog extends DogWords
    {
        protected $dogname = NULL;
        protected $dogwords = NULL;

        public function __construct($dogname)
        {
            $this->dogname = $dogname;
            $this->dogwords = new DogWords;
        }

        public function bark()
        {
            echo $this->dogname . "; Bark, bark, bark...";
        }
    }

    /**
    * Poodle
    */
    class Poodle extends Dog
    {

    }

    $Amy = new Poodle('DogConstructor');
    echo $Amy->dogwords->words[1];      // Fatal Error...
    echo $Amy->bark();      // DogConstructor; Bark, bark, bark...
 ?>
```

Comment: You should not have `Dog` extend `DogWords`. That's just silly.

Comment: Sure, Dog should inherit from Animals, Mammals, or HomePets. Because it should inherit from a class that is more abstract than dog itself. - For further readers...

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The problem is that you have an object inheriting from `<name>Words`. Having an abstract class which has a words property is one thing, having a dog be a subclass of `bark` is just wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`Protected` members cannot be used outside the scope of the subclass , if you want to access it outside it should be declared as `public` .

Please study from here [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: Ohh you right. I've seen in some frameworks that they use `B extends A` and then they use again `parent::__construct()`. But why would you do that exactly?

Comment: tats different that's for calling the parent constructor from derived class

Comment: But why would you call the constructor of the parent class when extending that class at the same time? When you make instance of `B` even when `parent::__construct()` will not be specified in `B`, PHP will still call the constructor of `A` because that's the nearest one. And `B` will still have all the properties and methods 'A' has.

Answer (score 1):

If you pretend to keep the variable to `protected`, why just don't do the following:

```
class DogWords
{
    protected $words = array('Wrr', 'Grr', 'Weeee', 'Houou');
}

/**
* Dog Class
*/
class Dog extends DogWords
{
    protected $dogname;
    protected $dogwords;

    public function __construct($dogname)
    {
        $this->dogname = $dogname;
        $this->dogwords = new DogWords;
    }

    public function bark()
    {
        return $this->dogname . "; Bark, bark, bark...";
    }
}

/**
* Poodle
*/
class Poodle extends Dog
{
     public function getDogWords()
     {
         return $this->dogwords->words;
     }
}

$Amy = new Poodle('DogConstructor');
$words = $Amy->getDogWords();
var_dump($words[1]);
var_dump($Amy->bark());
```

Example: http://codepad.org/GsmmHxev

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this fact: "Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes".

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

In order to access them, you need to make them both public:

```
class DogWords
{
    public $words = array('Wrr', 'Grr', 'Weeee', 'Houou');
}

/**
 * Dog Class
 */
class Dog extends DogWords
{
    protected $dogname = NULL;
    public $dogwords = NULL;

//... rest of the code

$Amy = new Poodle('DogConstructor');
echo $Amy->dogwords->words[1];      // Fatal Error...
echo $Amy->bark();      // DogConstructor; Bark, bark, bark...
?>
```

Now this prints: "GrrDogConstructor; Bark, bark, bark..."

Answer (score 0):

According to the rule of **OOP**, a **`protected`** member can only be accessed from inside the base class and the derived class(**immediate** and **non-immediate**)  but not from anywhere else.

But here you are trying to access the protected member of class `dog` i.e. `dogwords` in `echo $Amy->dogwords->words[1]` using the subclass `poodle`'s object i.e. `Amy`. Hence according to the principle you cannot access it this way.

### Perfectly legal...